# How to add a value into an array value in dictionary in python

Tags: python

**Given:**

```
 a={'sex': [[0.1834862385321101], [0.8165137614678899], [nan], [nan]], 
   'cp': [[0.7155963302752294], [0.08256880733944955], [0.1559633027522936]]}
```

**I want to add a value into the value of an array which key equals to 'sex' to get an out put as follow:**

```
a={'sex': [[0.1834862385321101, 1], [0.8165137614678899, 1], [nan], [nan]], 
    'cp': [[0.7155963302752294], [0.08256880733944955], [0.1559633027522936]]}
```

I tried to use update(), but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can do `a['sex'][0].append(1)` and `a['sex'][1].append(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use: `a['sex'][0].append(1)`

output:

```
{'sex': [[0.1834862385321101, 1], [0.8165137614678899], [nan], [nan]],
 'cp': [[0.7155963302752294], [0.08256880733944955], [0.1559633027522936]]}
```

Similarly, `a['sex'][1].append(1)` for the other value

Answer (score 1):

**This could another possible solution:**

```
a={'sex': [[0.1834862385321101], [0.8165137614678899], [], []], 'cp': [[0.7155963302752294], [0.08256880733944955], [0.1559633027522936]]}

for lst in a.get('sex', []):
    if lst:
        lst.append(1)

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
{'sex': [[0.1834862385321101, 1], [0.8165137614678899, 1], [], []], 'cp': [[0.7155963302752294], [0.08256880733944955], [0.1559633027522936]]}
```